# When does a semaphore issue a wait and when does it issue a signal?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling, mutual-exclusion, semaphore

In my textbook, *Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principles (9th Edition)* by William Stallings in chapter 5, it explains how semaphores work:

> The fundamental principle is this: Two or more processes can cooperate
> by means of simple signals, such that a process can be forced to stop at
> a specified place until it has received a specific signal. Any complex
> coordination requirement can be satisfied by the appropriate structure of
> signals. For signaling, special variables called semaphores are used. To
> transmit a signal via semaphore `s` , a process executes the primitive
> `semSignal (s)` . To receive a signal via semaphore s, a process executes
> the primitive `semWait (s)` ; if the corresponding signal has not yet been
> transmitted, the process is suspended until the transmission takes
> place.

I can't find a description in chapter 5 of when a semaphore would issue a semSignal vs a semWait (which are also sometimes called signal and wait). Can anyone describe the conditions under which semSignal would be issued vs a semWait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semaphore doesn't issue those.  A semaphore is an object that can be used by processes to coordinate between themselves.  Thus, a process will call semSignal or semWait on a shared semaphore.  We can't describe the conditions under which it will do that in general, because it's up to each process how it wants to use semaphores.  Semaphores are a primitive that can be used in many ways.  You should be able to find many examples online or in your textbook of using semaphores for coordination; that will give you some examples of specific processes and when those particular processes will invoke those operations on a semaphore.